# Epson L4150 linux

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Deseo instalar la impresora [Epson L 4150], en arquitectura 32bits (sin posibilidad de instalar 64bits).

Según la siguiente imagen, estaría instalado el paquete, pero la impresora no me aparece instalada ni aparecen los drivers necesarios en la BD.

Cualquier info se agradece.

[Imagen del instalador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCoZ3.png)

[Imagen de controladores presentes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDz0C.png)

-=======================================================

I want to install the printer [Epson L 4150], in 32bit architecture (without the possibility of installing 64bit).

According to the images, the package would be installed, but the printer does not appear to me installed nor do the necessary drivers appear in the database.

Comment: Please translate to English. Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Hello! I want to install the printer [Epson L 4150], in 32bit architecture (without the possibility of installing 64bit).

According to the images, the package would be installed, but the printer does not appear to me installed nor do the necessary drivers appear in the database.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? `epson-priner-utility` is not a driver but an app showing ink levels and other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El paquete instalado es solo la utilidad de impresión, no el controlador. El controlador puedes descargarlo de http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=ES&CN2=&DSCMI=104918&DSCCHK=282319be96fca696473b583fe973914c15ca90d3 Una vez instalado el sistema debería reconocer la impresora.

The package you installed it's only the printer utility, not the driver. You Can download the driver from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=ES&CN2=&DSCMI=104918&DSCCHK=282319be96fca696473b583fe973914c15ca90d3

After installing the driver the system should recognize the printer automatically.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!